# twilio sends 3 separate sms from dictionary and i need it to send once

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iteration, twilio

```
twilioCli = Client(accountSID, authToken)
message = twilioCli.messages.create(body="Your Shopping List:", from_ =twilioNum, to=myNum)


for keys,values in item_dict.items():
    if keys == "" or values =="":
        pass
    else:

        msg=twilioCli.messages.create(body='\n' + str(keys)+' '+ str(values) + '\n', from_=twilioNum, to=myNum)
```

how can i send sms in one msg vs multiples?
This is a very straight forward thing and I am confused. Please explain to me why twilio sends separate sms messages vs one?

program is simple, I have a grocery list, in the form of a dictionary and user checks items and enters a quantity. it iterates thru dictionary and should send checked items in the body of sms. But in my case i see multiple items. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have one message being sent in the second line that just contains the string "Your Shopping List:".

To send as one message, I'd modify how you iterate through the key, value pairs in your dictionary so you move the `for` loop to the end like this:

```
for keys,values in item_dict.items():
    if keys == "" or values =="":
        pass

msg2Send = "Your Shopping List: \n" + \
        ('\n'.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in item_dict.items()))
msg = twilioCli.messages.create(
body=msg2Send, from_="twilioNum", to="myNum")
```

Let me know if this helps at all!